# How can I change the dimension of a slide so that no object in the slide is modified in Microsoft PowerPoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

How can I change the dimension of a slide so that no object in the slide is modified in Microsoft PowerPoint?

When I do:

[image]

and reduce the size of the slide:

[image]

I get:

[image]

which changes the size of some of the objects present in the slide.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new blank PowerPoint slide with the desired dimensions.

`Select All` of the items on the original slide and `Copy`. `Paste` into the new slide.

Comment: Adding to @HighTechGeek's reply: You may want to start a new blank presentation based on the same template as the one you're resizing, or (probably better yet) make a copy of the original pres, delete everything on each slide AND on each master/layout, THEN resize the presentation and finally copy everything from each master/layout and each slide in the original to the corresponding master/layout or slide in the resized copy presentation.